# Fabric.js error while applying fliter on Image

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to load image from URL using "Fabricjs" while adding image to canvas, i am applying some "filters" on it, which generating an errors in console.

```
Security Error: The operation is insecure.
```

Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
      var ImageURL = "https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
        fabric.Image.fromURL(ImageURL, function(img) {
            img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveWhite({threshold: 60, distance: 10}));
            img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
            canvas.add(img.set({ left: 50, top: 50, angle: 30 }).scale(0.5));
        });
    })();

</script>
```

Please look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_anil/NYCQ5/5/) Link.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** do `getImageData()` on an **image loaded from a different domain**.
That is possibly throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're getting a CORS-related (or similar) error. More info here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/